# How to create a table in R to show my correlation matrix

Tags: database, r, matrix, export, correlation

I am new to R and I need help. I have created correlation matrix using the rcorr command. I would like to see this as a table so I can export it and email to my prof. The problem I am running into is this error message. I am at my wits end on how to fix it. I have tried data.frame command as well as write.table command.

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""rcorr"" to a data.frame

Comment: So... that's cause an rcorr object can't be coerced into a data.frame. Have you read the documentation for rcorr?

Comment: I have and have not been able to see the problem unfortunately. I have never encountered this problem before using data.frame. On the other hand I am not 100% certain this is the best way to proceed either.

Comment: It says: `rcorr returns a list with elements r, the matrix of correlations, n the matrix of number of observations used in analyzing each pair of variables,` so you need to conver the element `r` to a data.frame, not the whole rcorr object

Comment: Senor O, Thank you for the information. That actually clarifies few things for me. However, I need the statistical significance and and correlation matrix. I do not need the n values.

Comment: Cool then select the appropriate element based on the list it tells you in the documentation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might just look at the structure of the rcorr object. Ill create one with:

```
> rcx=rcorr(x)
```

then look at its stucture with:

```
> str(rcx)
List of 3
 $ r: num [1:10, 1:10] 1 0.0503 0.0309 0.0462 0.0719 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
 $ n: int [1:10, 1:10] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
 $ P: num [1:10, 1:10] NA 0.619 0.76 0.648 0.477 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "rcorr"
```

So it is an object with 3 components, the first and last one can be made into sensible tables. I am not sure which one of these you want to print.

If you need them to be dataframes this  will work

```
 df.rcx.r=data.frame(rcx$r)
```

or

```
 df.rcx.p=data.frame(rcx$P)
```

Then you can save these to a csv file with:

```
 write.csv(df.rcx.r,'correlationmatrix.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!! this worked. I am still unsure how to transfer it to the excel but I will play around with it. I appreciate all the help provided.

Comment: If you want it in excel, you just save it with `write.csv()`. excel opens csv files.

Comment: This may sounds stupid but how do you do that? I have tried to use that function and I got cannot coerce class "rcorr" into data.frame. So I input this function write.csv(as.matrix(pearson), "pearson.csv") and it worked. But when I tried to open it the matrix was messed up when I pulled in up in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code: `df.rcx.p = as.data.frame(rcx$P)`

The code `as.data.frame` coerces that table into a dataframe. 
Then when you save the file into a csv, just open it with Excel then you can save either as csv or Excel.